# Why did the author choose past simple in this case

Tags: past-tense

> The Complete Hemorrhage in Dub Collection
> by Jay Hinman! It struck me - based on the count of how many people streamed or downloaded them - that the 8 Hemorrhage in Dub spin-off podcasts I've done **were** actually kind of well-received, often even more so than our regular podcast.

I think "have been" would fit better with "have done". Using present perfect means that he has done these dub podcasts up to now, so they have been well received up to now. It is logical.

Does past simple  emphasize that each one individually  was well received not the whole lot.
Or does it mean that Jay is not sure that the next dub will be well received? It does not depend on him while he is sure to make a new dub podcast.

Comment: You could "justify" Present Perfect here, but personally I think Simple Past is actually "better" for this *exact* context. Note that the writer has *already* moved his "narrative context" to the past (to that point in the past when he was struck by the positive reception). So if you were ***looking*** for a chances to use "fancy, complex" verb forms, you could also justify *It struck me ... [that they] **had been** well-received*. But "normal" native Anglophones don't actively seek to maximise use of complex tenses (quite the opposite, in fact), so Simple Past is a perfectly sensible choice.

Answer (score 1):

It means that they were well received *at the time of broadcast*.  The speaker is implicitly talking about a past time (the time when they made the podcasts) so uses past tense.

A perfect tense would also be possible, if you wanted to connect to the present in some way. There is a connection to the present in the relative clause  (the podcast that I've done *until now*) but not in the main verb (they were well received *at that time*)